# Re-Useable ion-header component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

it seems altering the ionic page structure (ion-header followed by ion-content followed by ion-footer ) is breaking the layout. Even if i keep some content of ion-header on a different component and try to re-use it, it is not working. not working in the sense, ion-content is overlapping with ion-header ( if its content is coming from different component )

I can see some question on ionic forum 2 years back, and no answers yet.

Ref:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/reusable-component-for-ion-header-and-footer-ionic-v4/146964

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/recommendations-for-against-reusable-components-as-a-way-to-avoid-code-duplication/197064

can any one link the answers for this?

Comment: please post code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you'll find the answer in a very similar post that was asked some time ago (I just linked it to your post). It doesn't matter if you're using Ionic 3, 4 or 5, they all work in the same way when it comes to the `ion-header`. Hope it helps!